# ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from project (C:\django_projects\project\project\__init__.py)

Tags: python-3.x, django

This is my first Django project. I tried to execute the code available at:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/college-management-system-using-django-python-project/

Just made few changes such as removed staff module and modified the file names. The tree structure of my project is shown below:
c:
manage.py

```
project
   asgi.py
   settings.py
   urls.py
   wsgi.py
   __init__.py
  media
  static
  templates
  
  sudent_information_system
    admin.py
│   Admin_Views.py
│   apps.py
│   base.html
│   contact.html
│   forms.py
│   login.html
│   models.py
│   registration.html
│   Student_Views.py
│   tests.py
│   views.py
│   __init__.py
│
├───migrations
│       __init__.py
│
├───templates
│       home.html
│
└───__pycache__
        admin.cpython-37.pyc
        apps.cpython-37.pyc
        models.cpython-37.pyc
        __init__.cpython-37.pyc
```

The code in urls.py is as follows:

```
The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from . import HodViews, StudentViews

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('sudent_information_system.urls')),
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('contact', views.contact, name="contact"),
    path('login', views.loginUser, name="login"),
    path('logout_user', views.logout_user, name="logout_user"),
    path('registration', views.registration, name="registration"),
    path('doLogin', views.doLogin, name="doLogin"),
    path('doRegistration', views.doRegistration, name="doRegistration"),
    
    # URLS for Student
    path('student_home/', StudentViews.student_home, name="student_home"),
    path('student_view_attendance/', StudentViews.student_view_attendance, name="student_view_attendance"),
    path('student_view_attendance_post/', StudentViews.student_view_attendance_post, name="student_view_attendance_post"),
    path('student_apply_leave/', StudentViews.student_apply_leave, name="student_apply_leave"),
    path('student_apply_leave_save/', StudentViews.student_apply_leave_save, name="student_apply_leave_save"),
    path('student_feedback/', StudentViews.student_feedback, name="student_feedback"),
    path('student_feedback_save/', StudentViews.student_feedback_save, name="student_feedback_save"),
    path('student_profile/', StudentViews.student_profile, name="student_profile"),
    path('student_profile_update/', StudentViews.student_profile_update, name="student_profile_update"),
    path('student_view_result/', StudentViews.student_view_result, name="student_view_result"),


    # URL for Admin
    path('admin_home/', HodViews.admin_home, name="admin_home"),
    path('add_course/', HodViews.add_course, name="add_course"),
    path('add_course_save/', HodViews.add_course_save, name="add_course_save"),
    path('manage_course/', HodViews.manage_course, name="manage_course"),
    path('edit_course/<course_id>/', HodViews.edit_course, name="edit_course"),
    path('edit_course_save/', HodViews.edit_course_save, name="edit_course_save"),
    path('delete_course/<course_id>/', HodViews.delete_course, name="delete_course"),
    path('manage_session/', HodViews.manage_session, name="manage_session"),
    path('add_session/', HodViews.add_session, name="add_session"),
    path('add_session_save/', HodViews.add_session_save, name="add_session_save"),
    path('edit_session/<session_id>', HodViews.edit_session, name="edit_session"),
    path('edit_session_save/', HodViews.edit_session_save, name="edit_session_save"),
    path('delete_session/<session_id>/', HodViews.delete_session, name="delete_session"),
    path('add_student/', HodViews.add_student, name="add_student"),
    path('add_student_save/', HodViews.add_student_save, name="add_student_save"),
    path('edit_student/<student_id>', HodViews.edit_student, name="edit_student"),
    path('edit_student_save/', HodViews.edit_student_save, name="edit_student_save"),
    path('manage_student/', HodViews.manage_student, name="manage_student"),
    path('delete_student/<student_id>/', HodViews.delete_student, name="delete_student"),
    path('add_subject/', HodViews.add_subject, name="add_subject"),
    path('add_subject_save/', HodViews.add_subject_save, name="add_subject_save"),
    path('manage_subject/', HodViews.manage_subject, name="manage_subject"),
    path('edit_subject/<subject_id>/', HodViews.edit_subject, name="edit_subject"),
    path('edit_subject_save/', HodViews.edit_subject_save, name="edit_subject_save"),
    path('delete_subject/<subject_id>/', HodViews.delete_subject, name="delete_subject"),
    path('check_email_exist/', HodViews.check_email_exist, name="check_email_exist"),
    path('check_username_exist/', HodViews.check_username_exist, name="check_username_exist"),
    path('student_feedback_message/', HodViews.student_feedback_message, name="student_feedback_message"),
    path('student_feedback_message_reply/', HodViews.student_feedback_message_reply, name="student_feedback_message_reply"),
    path('student_leave_view/', HodViews.student_leave_view, name="student_leave_view"),
    path('student_leave_approve/<leave_id>/', HodViews.student_leave_approve, name="student_leave_approve"),
    path('student_leave_reject/<leave_id>/', HodViews.student_leave_reject, name="student_leave_reject"),
    path('admin_view_attendance/', HodViews.admin_view_attendance, name="admin_view_attendance"),
    path('admin_get_attendance_dates/', HodViews.admin_get_attendance_dates, name="admin_get_attendance_dates"),
    path('admin_get_attendance_student/', HodViews.admin_get_attendance_student, name="admin_get_attendance_student"),
    path('admin_profile/', HodViews.admin_profile, name="admin_profile"),
    path('admin_profile_update/', HodViews.admin_profile_update, name="admin_profile_update"),
    
]
```

The code in 'views.py' is as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponse, redirect,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import logout, authenticate, login
from .models import Students, AdminHOD
from django.contrib import messages

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')


def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'contact.html')


def loginUser(request):
    return render(request, 'login_page.html')

def doLogin(request):
    
    email_id = request.GET.get('email')
    password = request.GET.get('password')
    # user_type = request.GET.get('user_type')
    print(email_id)
    print(password)
    print(request.user)
    if not (email_id and password):
        messages.error(request, "Please provide all the details!!")
        return render(request, 'login_page.html')

    user = CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email_id, password=password).last()
    if not user:
        messages.error(request, 'Invalid Login Credentials!!')
        return render(request, 'login_page.html')

    login(request, user)
    print(request.user)

    if user.user_type == CustomUser.STUDENT:
        return redirect('student_home/')
    elif user.user_type == CustomUser.HOD:
        return redirect('admin_home/')

    return render(request, 'home.html')

    
def registration(request):
    return render(request, 'registration.html')
    

def doRegistration(request):
    first_name = request.GET.get('first_name')
    last_name = request.GET.get('last_name')
    email_id = request.GET.get('email')
    password = request.GET.get('password')
    confirm_password = request.GET.get('confirmPassword')

    print(email_id)
    print(password)
    print(confirm_password)
    print(first_name)
    print(last_name)
    if not (email_id and password and confirm_password):
        messages.error(request, 'Please provide all the details!!')
        return render(request, 'registration.html')
    
    if password != confirm_password:
        messages.error(request, 'Both passwords should match!!')
        return render(request, 'registration.html')

    is_user_exists = CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email_id).exists()

    if is_user_exists:
        messages.error(request, 'User with this email id already exists. Please proceed to login!!')
        return render(request, 'registration.html')

    user_type = get_user_type_from_email(email_id)

    if user_type is None:
        messages.error(request, "Please use valid format for the email id: '<username>.<staff|student|hod>@<college_domain>'")
        return render(request, 'registration.html')

    username = email_id.split('@')[0].split('.')[0]

    if CustomUser.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
        messages.error(request, 'User with this username already exists. Please use different username')
        return render(request, 'registration.html')

    user = CustomUser()
    user.username = username
    user.email = email_id
    user.password = password
    user.user_type = user_type
    user.first_name = first_name
    user.last_name = last_name
    user.save()
    
    if user_type == CustomUser.STUDENT:
        Students.objects.create(admin=user)
    elif user_type == CustomUser.HOD:
        AdminHOD.objects.create(admin=user)
    return render(request, 'login_page.html')

    
def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')


def get_user_type_from_email(email_id):
    """
    Returns CustomUser.user_type corresponding to the given email address
    email_id should be in following format:
    '<username>.<staff|student|hod>@<college_domain>'
    eg.: 'abhishek.staff@jecrc.com'
    """

    try:
        email_id = email_id.split('@')[0]
        email_user_type = email_id.split('.')[1]
        return CustomUser.EMAIL_TO_USER_TYPE_MAP[email_user_type]
    except:
        return None


# Create your views here.
```

The code in settings.py is as follows:

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'sudent_information_system.apps.SudentInformationSystemConfig', #This object was created for us in /catalog/apps.p
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

MEDIA_URL="/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"media")

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")



# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'sudent_information_system.CustomUser'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At your urls.py you have the following lines:

```
from . import views
from . import HodViews, StudentViews
```

Trying to import views from within the projects directory, but there are no such file inside.

These files are at 'sudent_information_system' app, where your view file is located, so:

```
from sudent_information_system import views, StudentViews
```

obs: From the strucure you posted in your question there is no such 'HodViews' , you either need the file or remove it from the imports to avoid a possible break.

I would like to complement, that there's the official [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/) which is a great place to start.

Comment: Thanks for solving the error and the tutorial link. I think wrong project has been chosen. However, I would appreciate, if you can help me in resolving the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sudent_information_system.urls"

Comment: It is hard to say for sure without any code. But it looks like you forgot to add your app ' sudent_information_system' to INSTALLED_APPS at Django settings.py file.